# What happens to a signal when it passes by diodes that are connected antiparallel to ground?

Tags: operational-amplifier, diodes, ground, distortion, offset

[image: Distortion pedal schematic]

What are diodes 1 and 2 doing in this schematic? This is the schematic for a distortion guitar pedal. Why doesn't all the current flow to ground through diode 2? How does diode 1 have any effect if current can't pass through it? Also, what is the effect of connecting pin 8, which is not connected to the op-amp, to pin 1 which is the offset voltage?

Comment: The diodes clip the signal to a nominal + or - 0.7 volts which distorts the signal above that level.

Comment: So-called diode clamp. Doesn't need to be connected to ground. Can be connected to supply voltages and each diode can be connected to a different voltage. Nor do you always need two anti-parallel. Sometimes you just need one in a particular direction. Depending on diode direction, it either stops the line from getting one diode voltage drop above or below the supply voltage it is connected to. Often used for things like ESD protection and voltage clipping.

Comment: Pin 8 clearly isn't N/C if the designer hooked up a capacitor to it. What op amp is it? As for the diodes, consider what the I-V curve of a diode looks like. And don't forget that the signal will swing both positive and negative with respect to ground. In this case, the diodes appear to be the source of the distortion this guitar pedal is meant to apply.

Comment: @Hearth it is a TL071 op-amp. It is my understanding that pin 8 is not connected to anything.

Comment: @user199827463 That appears to be the case. I'm not sure why it's connected here, then--I even went and checked the ancient TO-99 version and it has the same pinout as the DIP and SOIC ones. Are you sure it's not a mistake on the schematic?

Answer (score 1):

Silicon diodes start conducting at around 0.6V.  So two diodes in antiparallel will clip the AC waveform to a maximum of about ±0.6 to ±0.7V peak.

They are, presumably, what is providing the distortion in the pedal.

Comment: I understand that diodes will only allow a certain peak of voltage to pass, but why are they connected to ground instead of in antiparallel but in the direction the signal is traveling. In other words, why not connect one side to the capacitor, and the other side to the potentiometer?

Comment: If you did that, they would only pass signals with a voltage greater than 0.6 V or less than -0.6 V.  There wold be a +/- 0.6 V dead zone in your signal.

Comment: @SteveSh That makes sense. So if the clipping diodes are connected to ground they can clip all voltages? Does this only work for AC since the signal goes back and forth? If it was a DC signal would this configuration just act as a short to ground?

Comment: @user199827463 one diode clips positive voltages, and the other clips negative ones.  So a DC signal would still be clipped.

Comment: If the DC signal is above +0.6 V or below -0.6 V the yes, the signal would be clipped, or limited to those voltages.  But that's not your situation, since everything is AC coupled in that part of the circuit.

Answer (score 1):

Others stated that the diodes clip the signal: that is not quite correct.  C7 and C9 separate DC from the signal path containing the diodes so the operating voltage of the stage is floating.  Whenever one of the diodes starts to conduct, the operating voltage gets clamped to 0.7V away from ground until the input reverses direction at which point the signal is taken up at its current level.

However, the voltage on C8 follows with some delay due to R7 and the "filter" pot.  For filtering to make sense acoustically, the filter cutoff frequency will tend to be above the fundamental signal frequency.  Consequently, the modification of the "clamp but return from the clamped value already when signal changes direction" behavior will likely be moderate.

Answer (score 0):

> Also, what is the effect of connecting pin 8, which is not connected to the op-amp, to pin 1 which is the offset voltage?

Op-amp was an old [LM709](https://pdf1.alldatasheet.com/datasheet-pdf/view/9015/NSC/LM709.html) that was using a compensation capacitor + resistor (eventually) between pin1 and 8.